# C#/winforms layout: element with anchor right or bottom vanishes under parent container

Tags: c#, winforms

sometimes when i want a winforms control to be docked also to the right or bottom of the parent container (usually a UserControl), it's borders are extended way beyond the parent's right or bottom border, so that a part of it is not visible anymore. even though the anchor is set to right.

this only happens when the application is run. as long as i am in the designer view everything looks fine.

all i do is set the "Anchor" property of the control to "Right" for example.

is there a way to avoid this?

in this screenshot you can see the groupbox "Transition" extends way over it's parents extends to the right.

http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/08ffe2f5e7f4d33044840e68e0619152.png

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Anchor then you cannot use Dock (and vice versa).

> The Anchor and Dock properties are
>   mutually exclusive. Only one can be
>   set at a time, and the last one set
>   takes precedence.

I would check if your controls' parent is actually the control you think it is (it could be its parent :-) ).
Also check `Margin` property on the control and `Padding` property on the parent control.
Then check `AutoSize` property.

Answer (score 2):

Check your parent (UserControl) dock and anchor properties.  It appears to me that they have not been set and the UserControl not the items in the UserControl are extending past the borders.

Comment: thanks, yes the parent container is indeed the problem. sorry for the misunderstanding. it's anchor is set to top,left,right and then this problem happens!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are saying.  Can you reword the sentence?

If you are saying that when you resize the parent window, you want the control to also resize, you are on the right track.  You should change the anchor so that the control is anchored to left, top, right, and bottom.

Comment: yes, i know, it is hard to describe, but i will edit my post and reword it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dock to the right, at a constant height: anchor:=top,right
If you want to dock to the bottom right corner:         anchor:=bottom,right

What parent container are you docking in?  Is the control inside the parent?  If not, then it can resize over the top of it (since its not actually a child).

Comment: the parent container is a custom UserControl

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the anchoring is fine, but the problem is in the rendering. Have you tried calling Invalidate() in your container control?
I remember something similar happened to me a long time ago with a custom control. And I resolved it by forcing a repaint of the control.

Answer (score -2):

You probably have to mess around with the z-order of the controls.